# New Relic Infrastructure Agent can't access /proc/net/dev in Docker with Ubuntu-20.04 WSL2 integration

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-20.04, newrelic

New Relic Infrastructure agent in docker container can't access its /host/proc/net/dev directory and shows **file or directory not found error** when I tried to access that directory from the infrastructure agent container terminal. I've been attempting to bind that directory with the fake net as instructed in [here](https://scene-si.org/2016/11/22/bypassing-docker-network-isolation-hack/) but it didn't work either. Here are the container logs:
[New Relic Infra Agent Container Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idOYs.png)

Answer (score 0):

error means you dont have properly mapped volume /:/host in your docker container or privileged i guess it needs all directives

```
docker run \
-d \
--name newrelic-infra \
--network=host \
--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE \
--privileged \
--pid=host \
--cgroupns=host  # required on cgroup v2 \
-v "/:/host:ro" \
-v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" \
YOUR_IMAGE_NAME
```